# What's the best way to avoid repeating the name of the subject in a formal letter?

Tags: writing, formal-language

What's the best way to avoid repeating the name of the subject in the letter?

Assuming that I need to refer to the same person in a formal letter multiple times, what's the formal way to do so?

For example:
We want to declare the following things:

1. Jon Pitterson was graduated in 2023 successfully.
2. Jon Pitterson did not have any institute-related problems or debts during his study period in our institute.
3. Jon Pitterson....
4. Jon Pitterson...
5. Jon Pitterson....
6. Jon Pitterson...

To my eyes too many times mentioning the name makes it weird and exhausting.
Obviously, I've thought about omitting the Surname and that makes it look better, but still, I'm not sure if it's the formal way to do so.

(it's important to list them as a list rather than in a continuous way: Jon graduated in 2023 successfully and during his study in our institution he did not have any institute-related problems or debts etc...)

Comment: Since the reader knows who you are talking about, why not simply use "he" for subsequent points?

Comment: Well, it might be fine, but I'm not sure if it works for a formal letter. If you think it does, then here we are getting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard of the idea that the pronoun "he" might not be suitable for formal contexts. Why do you think that? Are you getting confused because in the context of scientific papers use of the first person pronouns "I" and "we" is generally discouraged?

Comment: I've never said the pronoun "he" might not be suitable for formal contexts. But I honestly don't know. I'm simply just asking because I don't know.

Comment: *Caveat:* There seems to be a push to ask people by which pronoun (he/she/it/hir, etc.) prefers to be addressed. However, that is far from universal, and in formal writing, "he" or "she" is acceptable. An alternative would be to refer by position or relationship in the letter, e.g., "the candidate", "the applicant", "my ex-employee". etc.

Comment: If it _has_ to be a list, 'he' looks better than repeating the name. Also, if it's a formal letter, 'Mr Pitterson' would be more appropriate than 'Jon'.

Answer (score 2):

In formal context use "He" for subsequent uses.  It is a matter of judgement when it becomes reasonable to repeat the name, and if you will use the full name or just the surname with an honourific.

> Jon Pitterson <s>was</s> graduated in 2023 <s>successfully</s>.
> He did not have any institute-related problems or debts during his study period in our institute. Mr Pitterson was placed third in his class of 40 students. His attendance to lessons was 85% and he ...

It's not important to present as a list. Formal letters don't present things as lists like that.

Or if it is a list and not a formal letter, then use bullets

> Jon Pitterson:
>
> - Graduated 2023
> - No debts during his period of study
> - Placed third in his class of 40

<sub>You either graduate or you don't, so "successfully" is not appropriate.  And it should be "He graduated", not "He was graduated".</sub>